# How to add a <Field /> when a button is clicked inside a Form with React & Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I need to find a way to add Formik's `<Field />` (type *select*) when a button is clicked inside the form. I'm trying to understand the [example given in the docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray), but I don't get it.

My React code (**I completely understand and see that this doesn't works the way intended, but this is what I have by now)** :

```
const dummyNorms = {
  normas: [
    { label: 'Norma 1', value: 'Norma 1 seleccionada' },
    { label: 'Norma 2', value: 'Norma 2 seleccionada' },
    { label: 'Norma 3', value: 'Norma 3 seleccionada' },
  ],
};

          <FormGroup>
            {/* ANCHOR Add Norm */}
            <FieldArray
              name='dischargeNorms'
              render={(arrayHelpers, index) => (
                <div>
                  <label>Norma de evaluación de descarga</label>
                  {
                    dummyNorms.normas.map(() => (
                      <div key={`norm-${index}`}>
                        <Field
                          name={`norm-${index}`}
                          type='select'
                          component={DUIKSelect}
                          options={
                            dummyNorms.normas
                        }
                        />
                      </div>
                    ))
                  }
                  <button
                    className='modal__addBtn'
                    onClick={() => arrayHelpers.insert(index, '')}
                    type='button'
                  >
                    <span className='btn__addNorm'>
                      <img src={svgAdd} alt='Añadir norma' />
                      AGREGAR NORMA
                    </span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              )}
            />
          </FormGroup>
```

Comment: Do you have example working somewhere like codesandbox?

Comment: @radulle I'm following this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-fieldarray-rossbulat-6mqfw?file=/src/index.js:306-316

Answer (score 1):

Each field in a Formik form has a name property, this name is a property path that belongs to the obfuscated form object that is in use. This form object is available as the values property on formProps (provided by the render method of the Formik component).

For example a field with the name of "propertyA" will have its value available at formProps.value.propertyA, while a field with the name of "propertyB[0].propertyC" will have its value available at formProps.value.propertyB[0].propertyC.

As the FieldArray you are using has the name property set to "dischargeNorms" all values insert using the associated arrayHelpers.insert will be inserted into the array available at formProps.values.dischargeNorms.

Instead of mapping your field components from dummyNorms.normas you should map them from formProps.values.dischargeNorms (where the new array nodes are being inserted). The fields should also use the name `dischargeNorms.${index}` so that they reference your intended property path.

```
const ExampleForm = () => {

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={{
                dischargeNorms: []
            }}
            render={formProps => {
                return (
                    <Form>
                        <FieldArray
                            name='dischargeNorms'
                            render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                                <div>
                                    <label>Norma de evaluación de descarga</label>
                                    {
                                        formProps.values.dischargeNorms.map((value, index) => (
                                            <div key={index}>
                                                <Field
                                                    name={`dischargeNorms.${index}`}
                                                    type='select'
                                                    component={DUIKSelect}
                                                    options={
                                                        dummyNorms.normas
                                                    }
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                    <button
                                        className='modal__addBtn'
                                        onClick={() => arrayHelpers.insert(index, '')}
                                        type='button'
                                    >
                                        <span className='btn__addNorm'>
                                        <img src={svgAdd} alt='Añadir norma' />
                                        AGREGAR NORMA
                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            )}
                        />
                    </Form>
                );
            }}
        />
    );
};
```